# how to display a wireframe in one view (front) and textured in another view (top) of the same object

Tags: edit-mode

I split my screen into different views but I cannot get different viewport display in each view for the same object.
For example - front view -> wireframe
- top view -> textured

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Like this? https://i.imgur.com/YsQmqxO.png

Comment: Hi. From your picture, it looks like I can use the viewport shading wireframe in one view and solid in the other one. I was focusing too much on the viewport display options in the object properties window.

Comment: I don't know of a way to make a single object display setting local to a single viewport...